# FTP connection suddenly stopped working

Tags: macos, ftp, osx-mountain-lion, filezilla, panic-transmit

I was working on my server one minute, the next minute for what appears to be no reason at all, I can't connect to any of my servers via FTP. I've been trying for 4 hours so far to find a solution.

I'm on OS X 10.8.5 and use Transmit for FTP.

Things I've tried already:

1. Downloaded FileZilla and tried connecting on this, but the same problem occurs.  It appears to detect the server, but won't connect.
2. Browser based FTP, and this works fine.
3. I tried turning on and off the firewall on OS X (this was not on)
4. Can't connect to FTP using iPad.
5. Restarting every device: my computer, iPad, my modem and router.

It would be great if anyone can help, or push me in the right direction.

Comment: @shoveshed - at point nr 5 you said you reset every device, do you mean factory reset? Also, are you able to ping your hostname?

Comment: browser-based ftp could be http with ajax etc etc. What have you done to ensure that the servers are listening on the proper port? Ar they all on one host? Have you contacted their tech support to see if they had a reboot or configuration change?

Comment: @horatio All different hosts, godaddy, 1&1, ovh. I don't know who to contact because i can't isolate the problem to one specific.

Comment: The servers are different, two unrelated devices can't connect. That means infrastructure: modem, router, ISP port blocking. In both FTP clients, have you tried toggling (on/or off) "FTP passive mode"?

Comment: @Rudolph sorry i meant "restarted every device". How do i ping my hostname, can you clarify please?

Comment: @horatio yes i already tried toggling on and off passive mode, no luck here either.  I checked on http://www.canyouseeme.org/ with port 21, and it says 'Error... connection timed out'.

Comment: does your router have "parental controls" or anything of the sort?

Comment: I understand you are familiar with FileZilla. Therefore the hostname (first field in FileZilla before Username & Password) would be the one we are looking for. Most hostnames are either named (ftp.domain1.com) or it would be an IP address. If you would like to ping that, open up your terminal, or cmd, and the ping the hostname.

Comment: You said browser based FTP works so that I suppose means you're saying your browser works as FTP client. So if that is so then your server is up. You mention though doing an online port scan, but it's not clear whether that failed due to a lack of port forwarding. There is no need for an online port scan as you can do a local one. Though if you are sure and right that your server is up then it may be pointless but Try `C:\>nmap -P0 -p21 192.168.1.5` . Or `C:\>telnet 192.168.1.5 21`.  where 192.168.1.5 is the IP you are going for.

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a firewall or using NAT? Try telnet-ing into each server. See if for some reason a port might have mistakenly been closed either by your ISP or a misconfiguration of a firewall. Can you ssh in?

Are you trying the standard ports? FTP-20,21

What about passive FTP? Are ports blocked?